# IIS AppPool naming convention

Tags: iis, naming-conventions

Is there a naming convention for naming AppPool (IIS)?

Explicit is great but should we add something like "AppPool" for external purpose (third party)? maybe for distinction between his site.

```
site name : MyProject
appPool name : MyProject

site name : MyProject
appPool name : AppPool_MyProject
```

Comment: As long as you don't use not-supported characters, you can give any name you like, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.administration.applicationpoolcollection.invalidapplicationpoolnamecharacters?view=iis-dotnet

Answer (score 1):

There are no convention for application pool naming.
By default, There was a naming convention for application pool identity. I mean if your application pool named MyProject. Then its application pool identity would be "IIS APPPOOL\MyProject".

Since application pool is only used to isolate different applications, you could naming anything you like. Most of time, we just use site name or sub-application's name as application pool's name.

Comment: How about spacing? Is it okay to have spacing for application pool name?